# SpriteKit - Showing SKEmitterNode

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skemitternode

How to show SKEmitterNode without parent node? I want my particles to stay at the static place, and emitter moves. But generated particles moving with parent node.

```
[someNode addChild:SKEmitterNode]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without parent node? SKScene:SKNode, so SKEmitterNode will always have parent node.

Try setting targetNode property on emitter node to self (current SKScene).

Comment: Awww, I forgot about SKScene. Thanks!